# JavaScript: findIndex() returns TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have this problem where I have a basic array containing numbers and I want to check if a certain number is in said array, and if it is, it returns the index where the number is. I get said number from a function. When I run the code, `findIndex(<number>);` gives me a `typeError: <number> is not a function`. Take a look at my code:

```
const numberProducer = function(n) {
  return n + 1;
};

var number = numberProducer(1);
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var isNumberInArray = arr.findIndex(number);

if (isNumberInArray === -1) {
  <do something>
}
else {
  <do something>
}
```

*I tried giving `findIndex()` a fixed value, and it still gives me the error.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findIndex` takes function as an argument and return the first element which meets given condition. If you want to use `findIndex()` you need to pass a function

```
arr.findIndex(x => x === number);
```

But in this case the most suitable option is to use `indexOf()`. When there is no condition and you only want to get the index of element then `indexOf()` is better

```
arr.indexOf(number);
```

```js
const numberProducer = function(n) {
  return n + 1;
};

var number = numberProducer(1);
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var index = arr.indexOf(number);

console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

`findIndex` accepts a callback, not a number. Hence:

```
const isNumberInArray = arr.findIndex((x) => x === number);
```

Is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no function and condition in arry.findIndex(). findIndex() finds value when a value in the function at findIndex(). There should be parameter for a flag and a value for condition. For example,

```
arr.findIndex((value) => value === number);
```

Inside findIndex(), there is ES6 so it's same for the below

```
function(value) { 
  return value === number 
});
```

function() { return } is same for () => {}. If the value meets number then findIndex returns index for the correct value.

Below it's reference of ES6

https://dev.to/sarah_chima/arrow-functions-in-es6-24

```js
const numberProducer = function(n) {
  return n + 1;
};

var number = numberProducer(1);
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//inside findIndex(), there should be function and condition
var isNumberInArray = arr.findIndex(
function(value) { 
return value === number 
});
console.log(number)
```